# RuntimeException in Android studio, on using maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to use maps, and am a newbie to java/android. I allowed AS to generate the xml and stuff.

I am using intent and 2 activity and need the 2nd activity to load maps.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

The code used is the basic code that is generated by AS.

The launcher activity code as follows;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    //    addButtonListner();
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("com.home.jop.Message", message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

The Manifest file is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jop.omgodess">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDrCYMoDWVPlcOiQAaaww7hXwW2fFqGZrQ" />
    <activity
        android:name="jop.omgodess.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="jop.omgodess.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="jop.omgodess.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I have been searching online for about a couple of days, but I am unable to comprehend the information that I read online. Could you help me out?

The error log is as follows;
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
[Fatal Error] :5:79: The prefix "android" for attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Sony vaio\AndroidStudioProjects\OMGodess\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Sony vaio\AndroidStudioProjects\OMGodess\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
  at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getPackageFromManifest(VariantConfiguration.java:945)
  at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getOriginalApplicationId(VariantConfiguration.java:740)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$_ConfigAction_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy:170)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$_ConfigAction_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$2.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:84)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:136)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:114)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig_Decorated.getBuildConfigPackageName(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo$4.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:460)
  at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:166)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo.getValue(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:458)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$Validator.validate(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:276)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing some steps, for example in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you should use `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Here a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) very well explain.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I loaded AS with default map activity, as a separate project and found that it was using "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" instead of maps.v2.API_KEY.

Comment: Well if you have any error message, could you add it to your post ?

Comment: apologize for the delay. I took a default map activity from AS and altered my preceding activities to get my stuff working. Yet the original project continues to throw error. I have updated the error logs.

Comment: Could you try to add at the beginning of your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`   Before your `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`